# samba_backup script setup

Tags: samba, backup, samba4

I downloaded the corresponding script from the sources of my packaged samba version. But with the packaged samba installation, there is no /var/lib/samba/etc.

Am I right, that /etc/samba should be moved to /var/lib/samba/etc and be symlinked back to /etc for the backupscript to work?

I just don't know what's supposed to be in the /var/lib/samba/etc directory, s.t. the backup works out.

[EDIT]

- It's ubuntu Xenial
- The backup script is the one mentioned in the samba wiki at https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Back_up_and_Restoring_a_Samba_AD_DC (take from the sources out of the git repo)

Comment: No. `/etc/samba/` should stay where it is. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Could you provide us the link to that "backup script"?

Comment: it's xenial.  The backup script is taken from the samba sources as mentionend here: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Back_up_and_Restoring_a_Samba_AD_DC